# Removing pop up tub drain assembly

Tags: drain, bathtub, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

I have a slow draining tub so I tried taking out the stopper but after unscrewing the stopper and the overflow plate there isn't anything more I could do, it seems like there is a one-peice L shaped rod from the lever to the stopper, I cant move one without the other, and I see no way to take it appart. Does anyone know about it and how to take it out? its not the plunger type neither the regular linkage type.    Kohler brand.

Comment: [This answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/18808/33) might help.

Comment: Its not one of those.

Comment: Can you post some photos? Is it a toe push stopper, or is there a lever that actuates the stopper?

Comment: I realize getting a response is unlikely as this post is quite old, but I have this exact same problem. Same set up, original from 1940s. Were you able to get it out anyway?

Comment: Unfortunately No. I had to cut the wall in back and replace the whole assembly with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I called Kohler and they tried to help me realy nicely, they found it for me (http://www.us.kohler.com/us/catalog/svg_viewer.jsp?productId=415967&diagram=0) and you can see that there is a elbow at the bottom in which the horizontal and the vertical parts are screwed in, so now after years of the installation the rod has got already a lot build up on it and its VERY hard to take it out:-(   (item is discontinued)