# How to disassemble a pop-up trip lever drain in tub?

Tags: plumbing, drain

My tub has a pop-up trip lever drain like this:

[image]

My tub is clogged; the water drains but very slowly. I tried to use an auger to clean it out but can't get past the spring.

How do I disassemble the pop-up trip lever drain so I can remove the clog?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. So, you  can remove the plug and lever  assembly? Have you tried pushing  the lever down so the spring rises up?

Comment: No, I cannot remove anything. I can only pull out the drain plug and the lever/overflow plate an inch or two. They are connected and I'm not sure how to disconnect them. If I push the lever down, the drain plug will close and I won't be able to get the auger down.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18794/) gives  you what you need.

Comment: I saw that post. The OP doesn't have a pop-up plunger like I do and the comments that refer to a pop-up plunger don't describe how to disassemble and remove the entire thing. I'm not sure how to remove the clog without removing the entire thing.

Comment: go to your local plumbing store ....if they have a replacement unit available, examine it to see how it is assembled ..... install instructions may also be in the box

Answer (score 1):

My pop-up sink drain had a similar problem.  I finally figured out that the top screws off the stem like the cap of a mushroom.  I had to show it who's boss and that I meant business, but it finally unscrewed and I was able to clean the drain.

You may also find that if you take the handle out, the spring is clogged with hair (that used to happen to me as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I would save time and get a drain opener. **Crystal Heat** is actually crystalized Sodium Hydroxide and Sodium Nitrate (dry). You can't use this when there is standing water. Pour about 1/4 cup down the drain and add a small amount of water. This stuff will boil and heat up to a point that it will actually melt grease and soap scum. It will also burn out hair clogs.

***Safe for all septic/sewage systems and pipes***

[image]