# Pulled a lot of stuff from Bath tub drain, now the clog is even worse!

Tags: bathroom, drain, bathtub, clog

My bathroom bathtub was very slow to drain, water will stand in the tub for long time. I bought the 20 ft long auger (advertised for bathtubs) and I can't believe I snaked through about 12 feet deep and pulled a lot of disgusting stuff. I was sure the drain will rain smooth now.

To my surprise, it's now completely clogged and water will not drain at all.

I re-snaked and this time I am not able to get pass the first turn in pipes (about 2 feet or so). I believed when pulling it out first, it probably deposited a lot of stuff there.

What could I do now? I keep locking the auger and turning but pushing in but this time it's not going any further. Any suggestions?

I have a typical bathtub, I believe like [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/18808/95327)

**Update**

I used plunger and managed to open the drain that way but still wanted to snake it 2nd time but won't get passed the same point. The drain is working now though.

Comment: Are you using a manual snake or motorized?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Yes its manual snake.

Comment: I'd suggest trying a motorized snake in the future. There are some relatively inexpensive ones designed to be used with a typical cordless drill/driver, [like this one from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-PowerSpin-Plus-57043/303644607?MERCH=REC-_-pip_alternatives-_-303644603-_-303644607-_-N&)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found (over many years and snaking hundreds of drains) that the ability to get past a bend in the line is directly related to your technique (read, *experience*) and the tool you are using.

Cheap cables are prone to flex too much and are difficult to get around some bends, especially if you've kinked it (although I keep a few cheap ones, I call them "noodles", for specific times when I *need* a soft cable). Also the cable size matters, small cable for small drain, larger cable for larger drain.

I highly recommend that you invest in a commercial quality auger with a cable that has a stiffening element in the core, like this:

[image]

I have owned the same one for >25 yrs. and have never encountered a home branch line (tub, shower, sink) that I could not successfully clear with it.

Comment: They are around $100 US, but it will pay for itself over, and over, and over...

Comment: @YEAH, LIKE THE FIRST TIME IT PREVENTS HAVING TO CALL A PLUMBER... LOL

Comment: Thank you, you answer makes sense and given your experience, I have accepted this as answer. My drain is running smooth now but will try this if I encounter the same problem again. I bought my auger for $20 from lowes so I guess there will be a difference with $100 auger. [Mine](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Cobra-1-4-in-x-20-ft-Music-Wire-Drain-Auger/1000734040) does have good reviews but probably not a professional one